# Understanding the IR flow

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am finding difficulty in understanding the flow of the LLVM's IR. The motive behind this work is to convert a given c/c++ program into it's SSA representation.
I found that https://releases.llvm.org/3.4.2/docs/tutorial/LangImpl7.html, we can get SSA from LLVM's IR by using the -mem2reg pass. 
As a beginner I find it difficult to understand the flow of the IR, although I could not understand at least some of the different types of instructions used such as load, store, icmp.fcmp, br label, br i1 etc.
However, the sequence in which the blocks occur is confusing to me. If there is any material that help me understand the flow would be helpful.

I see that llvm also provide an interface to have a visual representation using the opt option "-view-cfg" and using "dot -Tpdf cfg_file.dot -o cfg.pdf". Though it helped a lot but there are flow connections which I am not able to make sense out of it.

Now my main problem is I am unable to understand the last five blocks. What is the sequence and control flow of these (last five) blocks? The goal is to create SSA(single static assignment) of the program using this IR representation of LLVM.
Please find below the IR and the source code of the C program. Also find a link to my google drive the CFG file.

> **LLVM's IR**

```
    call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata %struct.INPUT_VAL* %input, metadata !31, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !42

    call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata %struct.RETURN_VAL* %ret_val, metadata !32, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !43

    call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i32 2, metadata !33, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !44

    call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata double 7.000000e+01, metadata !36, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !45

    call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata double 6.600000e+01, metadata !37, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !46

    %temperature = getelementptr inbounds %struct.INPUT_VAL, %struct.INPUT_VAL* %input, i64 0, i32 0, !dbg !47
    %tmp = load double, double* %temperature, align 8, !dbg !47, !tbaa !48
    call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata double %tmp, metadata !35, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !53
    %cmp = fcmp oge double %tmp, 6.600000e+01, !dbg !54
    %cmp1 = fcmp olt double %tmp, 7.000000e+01, !dbg !56
    %or.cond49 = and i1 %cmp, %cmp1, !dbg !57
    br i1 %or.cond49, label %if.end9, label %if.else, !dbg !57

    %cmp2 = fcmp ult double %tmp, 7.000000e+01, !dbg !58
    br i1 %cmp2, label %if.else4, label %if.end9, !dbg !60

    %cmp5 = fcmp olt double %tmp, 6.600000e+01, !dbg !61
    %. = zext i1 %cmp5 to i32, !dbg !63
    br label %if.end9, !dbg !63

    %.pr52 = phi i32 [ 2, %entry ], [ 0, %if.else ], [ %., %if.else4 ]
    %tmp1 = load i32, i32* @thermostat.off_counter, align 4, !dbg !64, !tbaa !66
    %cmp10 = icmp sgt i32 %tmp1, 4, !dbg !68
    %tmp2 = load i32, i32* @thermostat.on_counter, align 4, !dbg !69
    %cmp11 = icmp sgt i32 %tmp2, 4, !dbg !70
    %or.cond = or i1 %cmp10, %cmp11, !dbg !71
    br i1 %or.cond, label %if.then12, label %if.end9.if.end13_crit_edge, !dbg !71

    %.pr.pre = load i32, i32* @thermostat.chatter_detect, align 4, !dbg !72, !tbaa !66
    br label %if.end13, !dbg !71

    store i32 0, i32* @thermostat.chatter_detect, align 4, !dbg !74, !tbaa !66
    br label %if.end13, !dbg !75

    %.pr = phi i32 [ %.pr.pre, %if.end9.if.end13_crit_edge ], [ 0, %if.then12 ], !dbg !72
    %cmp14 = icmp eq i32 %.pr52, 0, !dbg !76
    br i1 %cmp14, label %if.end16, label %if.then15, !dbg !77

    %inc = add nsw i32 %.pr, 1, !dbg !78
    store i32 %inc, i32* @thermostat.chatter_detect, align 4, !dbg !78, !tbaa !66
    br label %if.end16, !dbg !79

    %tmp3 = phi i32 [ %inc, %if.then15 ], [ %.pr, %if.end13 ], !dbg !80
    %cmp17 = icmp sgt i32 %tmp3, 2, !dbg !82
    %brmerge = or i1 %cmp17, %cmp14, !dbg !83
    br i1 %brmerge, label %if.end25.thread, label %if.end25, !dbg !83

    store i32 0, i32* @thermostat.on_counter, align 4, !dbg !84, !tbaa !66
    %inc22 = add nsw i32 %tmp1, 1, !dbg !87
    store i32 %inc22, i32* @thermostat.off_counter, align 4, !dbg !88, !tbaa !66
    br label %.thread, !dbg !89

    %inc24 = add nsw i32 %tmp2, 1, !dbg !90
    store i32 %inc24, i32* @thermostat.on_counter, align 4, !dbg !90, !tbaa !66
    store i32 0, i32* @thermostat.off_counter, align 4, !dbg !88, !tbaa !66
    %switch.selectcmp = icmp eq i32 %.pr52, 1, !dbg !89
    br i1 %switch.selectcmp, label %.thread, label %bb, !dbg !89

    %.ph56 = phi double [ 2.000000e+01, %if.end25.thread ], [ 1.000000e+02, %if.end25 ]
    br label %bb, !dbg !89

    %tmp4 = phi double [ %.ph56, %.thread ], [ 7.000000e+01, %if.end25 ]
    call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata double %tmp4, metadata !34, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !92
    %u37 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.RETURN_VAL, %struct.RETURN_VAL* %ret_val, i64 0, i32 0, !dbg !93
    store double %tmp4, double* %u37, align 8, !dbg !94, !tbaa !48
    ret %struct.RETURN_VAL* %ret_val, !dbg !95
```

**C Program**

```
    #include "thermostat.h"  //contains structure information

    #ifdef DEBUG
      #include<stdio.h>
    #endif

    RETURN_VAL* thermostat(INPUT_VAL* input, RETURN_VAL* ret_val)
    {
        static int chatter_detect;
        static int previous_command_to_heater;
        static int on_counter, off_counter;
        static int command_to_heater;
        int chatter_limit=2;
        double u, room_temp;
        double MAX_TEMP=70.0, MED_TEMP=66.0;

    //  int NO_HEAT=0, NORMAL_HEAT = 2, FAST_HEAT = 1;

     room_temp = input->temperature;

        if(room_temp >= MED_TEMP && room_temp < MAX_TEMP)
            command_to_heater = 2;
        else if(room_temp >= MAX_TEMP)
            command_to_heater = 0;
        else if(room_temp < MED_TEMP)
            command_to_heater = 1;
        else
            command_to_heater = previous_command_to_heater;

        if(off_counter >= 5 || on_counter >= 5)
            chatter_detect = 0;

        if(command_to_heater != previous_command_to_heater)
            chatter_detect++;

        if(chatter_detect > chatter_limit)
            command_to_heater = previous_command_to_heater;

        if(command_to_heater == 0) {
            on_counter = 0;
            off_counter++;
        } else {
            on_counter++;
            off_counter = 0;
        }

        if (command_to_heater==0) 
            u = 20;
        else if (command_to_heater==1) 
            u = 100;
        else if (command_to_heater==2) 
            u = 70;
        ret_val->u = u;
      return ret_val;
    }
```

Link to CFG file generated out of this IR https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wIvXR5PosWWViM4fo_jEaLpXkCbhYGSE

Any help or pointer in this direction would be great.
Thanks and sorry for making the question complex and lengthy. Please feel free to clarify if there is any missing information.

Comment: What you're looking at isn't complete. `br label %if.end9` jumps to the label if.end9, and your code doesn't contain `if.end9:`. I think you'll find the control flow easy to understand once you have the labels. A branch such as `br i1 %brmerge, label %if.end25.thread, label %if.end25` always branches, either to if.end25.thread or to if.end25, so the control flow is explicit, you're just missing the labels that are necessary to read it.

Comment: Thanks for a quick respond.

Comment: Are you referring the missing label in the IR? If so, I do have an interface that can give me access to the label name. Please refer to the CFG link above, that shows clearly the beginning of each block by their label.

Comment: As mentioned by @arnt. The %if.end9 label is not in the  IR. It seems we can refer to the CFG.

Comment: The CFG also contains arrows that answer your questions...

Comment: I am sorry I think am not able to convey my problem in details. I am trying to scan through the IR (which is in SSA form of the C program) line by line and trying to create an SMT formula for some requirement. So how do I interpret the flow into some "ite" as in SMT formula?